# onclick event trigger on google map with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a google map on the map there are user's markers. The marker is updating after 5 seconds & showing real location with latitude and longitude. I have a sidebar which contains user's names which users markers are on the map. Besides the user's name there is a checkbox. Now what I want when I click on check box then that user's marker will have to show on the center of map & if I check another user's checkbox then that user also appears on the center along other users. If no checks are marked then all markers will show on the map.

```
<script>

      var iconlink = "http://newgen-bd.com/turzo/images/Turzo.png";
      var headiconlink = "http://newgen-bd.com/turzo/images/home.png";
      var map;
      var markers;
      var globalrmark;
      var mapMarkers = [];
      var headLatLng;
      var prevPointMap = [];
      var markarMap = [];



  var customLabel = {
    restaurant: {
      label: 'R'
    },
    bar: {
      label: 'B'
    }
  };

function initMap() {        
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.75, 90.3517887),
      zoom: 15
    });
    //var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    //trafficLayer.setMap(map);

    //Mirpur Head Office Location - 23.7833861,90.3517887

    //----
     headLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.7833861, 90.3517887);
    // 23.755423,90.3741037
    var headQuarter = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: headLatLng ,
    map: map,
    title: 'Head Office!',
    icon: headiconlink
    });

    //--Start
    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl("<?php echo base_url('clientmap/position')?>", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
         markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {


          var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));


          prevPointMap[id] = point;
          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};

     //marker resize
         var iconresize = {
        url: "http://35.202.63.12:3000/marker/"+name, // url
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(70, 70), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
    };
          //marker resize end

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon : iconresize
            //icon : "http://192.168.10.145:3000/marker/"+name
          });
         //bounds start
         // var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          latlngbounds.extend(point);
          map.fitBounds(latlngbounds); 
          //bounds end

             marker.addListener('click', function(event) {

            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            map = marker.getMap();    
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()); // set map center to                                                   
            marker position
            smoothZoom(map, 16, map.getZoom());

            });
           markarMap[id] = marker;
           mapMarkers.push(marker);

        });//end foreach


          });//end download url
           //-------end

            var counter = 0;
            interval = window.setInterval(function() { 
              counter++;
              // just pretend you were doing a real calculation of
              // new position along the complex path
             var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
            downloadUrl("<?php echo base_url('clientmap/position')?>", 
           function(data) {        
           var xml = data.responseXML;
           markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');

          Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');

          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));


          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name + " at  " + prevPointMap[id]
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};



         if(id in markarMap){

         markarMap[id].setPosition(point); 
         prevPointMap[id] = point;


         }else
        {
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             map: map,
             position: prevPointMap[id],
             label: icon.label,
             animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
             icon : iconresize
             //icon : "http://192.168.10.145:3000/marker/"+name
           });



           marker.addListener('click', function() {
             infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
             infoWindow.open(map, marker);
           });

        markarMap[id] = marker;
        mapMarkers.push(marker);

       // marker.setPosition(pos);

     markarMap[id].setPosition(point); 
     prevPointMap[id] = point;

}


        });
      });
      //-------end

              if (counter >= 1000*500) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);   
              }
            }, 10*500);


    } // end of init

    //zoom start
   function smoothZoom (map, max, cnt) {
    if (cnt >= max) {
    return;
    }
    else {
    z = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed',   
    function(event){
        google.maps.event.removeListener(z);
        smoothZoom(map, max, cnt + 1);
    });
    setTimeout(function(){map.setZoom(cnt)},50); 
    }
   }
    //zoom end

    // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
    function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++) {
      mapMarkers[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }

  // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
  function clearMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(null);
  }

  // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
  function deleteMarkers() {
    clearMarkers();
    mapMarkers = [];
  }

  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing(){}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you please please please format your post properly with punctuation? I  don't mean to sound rude, but I honestly don't even know what you're asking.

Comment: updated please check